# FireStore reads question, how will limiting reads affect the price

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning more about using Firestore and its reads, I know I can query a collection to mach a document and that will be one read, but what if I was to direct the get to a document id? such as

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Artists").document("ID4").getDocument
```

If I have 50 artists (50 documents) with unique ids and I point to a specific one, like above, will it still class them as 50 reads? or just 1 ?

or will I be better to write,

```
let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("Artists").whereField("iD", isEqualTo: "iD4"!)
    query.limit(to: 1).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
```

I have the iD in the document field as well as it being the document id.

Comment: I moved the tags from the title into the actual tags section of your question. Please refrain from including tags in the title, as it makes the title harder to read, and ensure to include the relevant tags on your question going forward, as that helps readability of your question and thus makes it more likely that someone will help.

Comment: Thank You and noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you are reading a single document, so you will be charged for a single document read operation.

In your second example you have a query that also only reads a single document, so you will also be charged for a single read operation.